# DevExpress AspxGridview Filter between two dates and two datepickers in the same filter

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

Hello I add a second date picker in a filter column in the grid with this code.

```
   Protected Sub GridManageProject_AutoFilterCellEditorInitialize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewEditorEventArgs) Handles GridManageProject.AutoFilterCellEditorInitialize

    If (e.Column.Caption.Equals("Date début")) Then

        e.Editor.Controls.Add(New ASPxDateEdit())
    End If

End Sub
```

If I pick a date, the event start before I pick the another. How to insert 2 date in the filter grid and start the event just after pick the second date and catch the  value in this event for the 2 datepicker filter

```
  Protected Sub GridManageProject_AutoFilterCellEditorCreate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewEditorCreateEventArgs) Handles GridManageProject.AutoFilterCellEditorCreate

    If e.Column.Name = "StartDate" Then

        ???

    End If
```

Comment: My experience with the DevExpress is that they answer _all_ questions fast, detailed and accurate. I therefore recommend that you ask the question directly through the DevExpress support options to get a decent answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E1990.aspx) solution that illustrates how to implement “Date Range Filtering”.